# how to cleanly uninstall my python packages with pip3 or any other way?

Tags: pip, uninstallation, setuptools, python-3.4

this is my setup.py file for installing my python program, after the installation using `python3 setup.py install` an entry to my program was created named `testmain` , when i did `pip3 freeze` it showed `abc==0.1` in its output ,so i uninstalled it using pip3 with `pip3 uninstall abc` , though the packages were uninstalled but there still existed the entry `testmain` on my path , is there a way that pip3 also removes this entry during the uninstall or any other way that i can cleanly uninstall my programs under same scenario ?

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='abc',
      version='0.1',
      description='test',
      url='http://github.com/rjdp',
      author='rajdeep',
      author_email='rajdeep.sharma@rtcamp.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['cli'],
      install_requires=[
      'cement',
      ],
      entry_points = {
      'console_scripts': ['testmain=cli.abc:main'],
      },
      zip_safe=False)
```

Answer (score 45):

Instead of python3 setup.py install use:

```
pip3 install .
```

then

```
pip3 uninstall abc
```

This will remove testmain.

I had the same question today and spent the entire morning trying to figure out why the script wouldn't uninstall. Nothing worked until I saw Ramana's answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38692/how-does-one-remove-applications-installed-through-python-setup-py-install

"You should always install Python apps with "pip". pip supports uninstall option." and the example in the commment on how local path is supported.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't binaries, which were compiled with gcc during pip install