# Uninstall a package installed with `pip install .`

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

When installing Python packages from development repositories, I usually navigate to wherever `setup.py` is found and do

```
pip install .
```

This installs the package in `$HOME/.local/`. Nice.

How can I *uninstall* a package installed this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to cleanly uninstall my python packages with pip3 or any other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346217/how-to-cleanly-uninstall-my-python-packages-with-pip3-or-any-other-way)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply run `pip uninstall package-name`

That's all you need.

For more follow this link : https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/