# How to install Django on Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 if that helps.

I tried installing using pip. It keeps saying it's successful but this is the result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.11.17)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django) (2014.10)
```

Now, I tried upgrading it and it still shows the same error.

I tried using pip3. It's successful but when I try to import it on python 3.0, it shows this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I also tried installing using virtualenv. It still doesn't work.

If it helps, this is the error which shows when I try installing using pip3:

```
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./pgadmin4/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./pgadmin4/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django) (2018.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most sane setup is to install django in a `virtualenv` environment.

Inside your project's directory, do like this:

```
python3 -mvenv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip install django
```

Note that when the `virtualenv` is activated, `python` and `pip` are added to `PATH` from the `virtualenv`, so you don't need to worry about using `python3` or `pip3`. And all your packages will be installed under `./venv`, well isolated from everything else in your system.

To deactivate the `virtualenv` in the current shell, run `deactivate`.
Just don't forget to re-run `. ./venv/bin/activate` every time you want to work on the Django project.

Comment: Isn't pip for python2.7? I believe its pip3 for python3.6+.

Comment: @kokeen If you just say "pip", it can be anything. It can be an alias to `pip3`. In the example I gave, it will be `./venv/bin/pip`, therefore the appropriate version for the `venv`, matching the version of the Python binary that was used to create it, in this example `python3`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I mentioned it as when I started working in python3 I used to face errors as I was more used to pip than pip3.

Comment: @kokeen When working with Python, it's best to create a virtual environnent like this, and then you don't need to worry about versions. You can have perfectly isolated projects, using different versions of dependencies and Python interpreter itself, independently. You just have to remember to run the activation script every time before use.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I do now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this just for testing 
if you want to use in virtual environment

Start new project in new directory

```
mkdir djangoTest
cd djangoTest
```

Create new environment named venv

```
python3 -mvenv venv
```

Then activate it

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

install django in it (you have to use always pip instead pip3 in venv)

```
pip install django
```

And create your django project named testDjango

```
django-admin startproject testDjango
cd testDjango
```

Create new app in it

```
python manage.py startapp testApp
```

And finally try run server with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can remove existing dependencies directly. If Django is already present, just uninstall it using pip3 and then reinstall it. I had the same issue with TensorFlow. I did a clean uninstall and then used a TensorFlow wheel for a new install.

```
pip3 uninstall django
```

You can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346217/how-to-cleanly-uninstall-my-python-packages-with-pip3-or-any-other-way/36291541) for more details.